# PHP + Rabbitmq. Как получить количество сообщений в очереди?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Как из php скрипта определить количество сообщений в очереди? Вот мой код:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'user', 'pass');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->basic_consume('sms_inbox', '', true, false, false, false, $callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Это костыль для решения этого вопроса. Как сделать вывод количества сообщений в очереди средствами php без функции `exec()` у меня так и не вышло

```
$content = exec('rabbitmqctl list_queues|grep sms_inbox');
preg_match_all('/sms_inbox(.+)/', $content, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$cnt = trim($result[1][0]);
```

Comment: Это костыль для решения этого вопроса. Как сделать вывод количества сообщений в очереди средствами php без функции exec() у меня так и не вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
$queue = new AMQPQueue($channel);
$queue->setName('sms_inbox');
$queue->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);
echo $queue->declare() . PHP_EOL; // до 1.2.0
```

или с версии rabbitmq 1.2.0:

```
echo $queue->declareQueue() . PHP_EOL; // с 1.2.0
```

Метод [`declare()`](http://php.net/manual/fa/amqpqueue.declare.php) кроме того, что объявляет очередь, возвращает количество сообщений в очереди.

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the message count.

С версии amqp 1.2.0 [`AMQPQueue::declare()` deprecated](https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.4.0) и нужно использовать `AMQPQueue::declareQueue()`.

Comment: Это объявит очередь, но ответ совершенно точно не будет ничего содержать количество сообщений

Comment: @Etki у меня работает вариант с `->declareQueue()` - возвращает кол-во сообщений. с `declare` тоже работает, но с ошибкой, т.к. [declare](https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.4.0) deprecated с 1.2.0.